# fetch all results as an array with integer index only

Tags: php, fetch

So ok before you start talking about that I should have looked it up and stuff, I did but found nothing that matches my needs exactly,so lets see;

Here is a sample from php.net describing how is it possible to fetch all results at once([click link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)),

look at Example #1 and tell me please how do I modify the given code to receive this result instead:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => pear
        [1] => green
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => watermelon
        [1] => pink
    )

)
```

sorry for inconvenience and not using code spans,I just don't know how to do it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use below to get index array result

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Answer (score 2):

in the given example, you need to change the line

`$result = $sth->fetchAll();`   to

`$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);`

Here's the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) for `PDO::fetch`.

Comment: I have a question for you and for GBD,does a CONST value that is made for fetch work with fetchAll,because FETCH_NUM is for fetch only !, ?

Comment: reading http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php, seems like it would work for both, coz there are constants that are specified, when they dont work with `fetchAll()`